# Как правильно задать стили CSS?

Tags: css

Хочу изменить готовый код tooltip, чтобы 1-я подсказка появлялась вверху, а вторая, например, внизу. 
Ввела класс 'b'. Не работает, как надо, и span .b, span.b.  Как добиться желаемого?

```
<head>
<style>
.tooltip {
  outline: none;
  cursor: help; 
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
 }
.tooltip span{
  margin-left: -999em;
  position: absolute;
}
.tooltip:hover span{
  color:#111; border:1px solid #DCA; background:#FFFF33;
  z-index: 99;
  margin-left: 0; width: 200px;
}
.tooltip:hover span {    
  left: 1em; 
  bottom: 1em; 
}
.tooltip:hover span .b {    
  left: 1em; 
  top: 1em; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</br>
<a class="tooltip">Подсказка1 <span> Содержимое подсказки 1</span> </a>
</br></br></br>
<a class="tooltip" >Подсказка2 <span class='b'> Содержимое подсказки 2</span> </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря, не совсем понял вопрос, но всё же попробую ответить.

```
     .tooltip:hover span {    
       left: 1em; 
       bottom: 1em; 
     }
     .tooltip:hover span .b {    
       left: 1em; 
       top: 1em; 
     }
```

Написано как-то некорректно. Попробуй разделить всё.
Например:

```
 <style> 
 .tooltip {   
 outline: none;  
 cursor: help;   
  text-decoration:none;   
 position: relative;  
 } 
 span.a
 {   left: 1em;    bottom: 1em;  }
 span.b {   left: 1em;    top: 1em;  }
 <a class="tooltip">Подсказка1 <span class"a"> Содержимое подсказки
 1</span> </a> </br></br</br>
 <a class="tooltip" >Подсказка2 <span class="b"> Содержимое подсказки
 2</span> </a>
```

Comment: Спасибо! В моем варианте приоритет .tooltip:hover span оказывался выше, чем .tooltip:hover span .b

Comment: Не за что, рад помочь